# Use Cornerstone Plugin outside of Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: plugins

All,
At risk of having a plugin specific question I feel that it could be beneficial for a lot of others as the X theme has sold a lot of copies and I believe quite a few people use it. The theme uses Cornerstone page builder to create new pages/posts but the problem is that for new pages/posts you have to be in the Admin Dashboard. My issue is that I don't want to give users access to the Dashboard and want to keep them on the frontend of my site where they can create new posts etc. Has anyone discovered a way to create posts on the frontend outside of the dashboard?

In their construct function they have the following code:

```
if ( !is_admin() )
        return;


add_action( 'admin_menu',            array( $this, 'optionsPage' ) );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
add_filter( 'page_row_actions',      array( $this, 'addRowActions' ), 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'post_row_actions',      array( $this, 'addRowActions' ), 10, 2 );
add_action( 'admin_notices',         array( $this, 'updateNotice' ), 20 );
```

I tried to enqueue the same scripts by adding an if statement and then changing the enqueue action to this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
```

However I must be missing something (or a lot) because it's still not working as I would expect it to so turning to here for help to see if anyone has had any luck on this.

Thanks in advance!